# Calendarize plugin - output 'To' time

Tags: plugins

I'm using Calendarize and I'm not sure how I can grab the 'To' time?

https://plugins.craftcms.com/calendarize

```
 {% set monthStart = now|date_modify('-1 day') %}
 {% set monthEnd = '2022-01-31' %}
 {% set occurrences = craft.calendarize.between(monthStart, monthEnd, { 
 section: ['events'] }) %}
 {% for occurrence in occurrences %}
<h2>{{ occurrence.title }} - {{ occurrence.next|date('D j M') }}</h2>
{{ occurrence.description }}

//START TIME
{{ occurrence.next|date('H:ia') }}-
//TO TIME???
{{ occurrence.next|date('H:ia') }} occurrence.endTime.format('H:ia')}}
```

[image]

```
{% endfor %}
```